# Latex - How to make system equations bold? (systeme)

Tags: latex, tex

When using the systeme package to create systems of equations, how can I configure the base formats in order to, for instance, make all my systems bold? What about individual systems?

So far I've made it work using \bm{} in each line of the system but it's not practical at all.

Comment: http://www.sascha-frank.com/latex-italics.html seems to indicate that `\bfseries ... \normaltext` could work.

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\boldmath` to switch to bold font for math contents, and `\unboldmath` to switch it off. They must be used outside the math code.

```latex
\boldmath
\[
   1 + x = \alpha.
\]
$2 \times (1 + 1)$
\unboldmath
\[
   1 + x = \alpha.
\]
$2 \times (1 + 1)$
```